# The limit of $f$ or the limit of $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, terminology

I have read before that $f$ denotes the function $f$ whilst $f(x)$ denotes the value of the function $f$ at $x$. What is right? To say that the limit of $f$ as $x$ tends to $a$ is $L$ or to say that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $a$ is $L$? Put another way, is it the limit of the function at $x$ or the limit of the value of the function at $x$? If both are correct, what is more precise?

Hopefully, you'll understand what I mean.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case, I personally think it is more precise to say $f(x)$ converges to $L$ as $x$ converges to $a$. But it should always be clear what is meant if you simply say $f$ converges to $L$. However, I also think the latter is somewhat nicer to read. But this is largely a choice you can make for yourself.

Comment: As I see that all answers are useful and correct, I will leave the question for a while and mark the answer with the most votes as the correct one. Thanks, you have all been very very helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spivak, in chapter 5 of Calculus, says this:

> The equation \begin{equation*} \lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \ell \end{equation*} 
>   has exactly the same meaning as the phrase
>   \begin{equation*} f \text{ approaches } \ell \text{ near } a.\end{equation*}

He goes on to say:

> Notice that our new notation introduces an extra, utterly irrelevant
>   letter $x$, which could be replaced by $t$,$y$, or any other letter
>   which does not already appear -- the symbols \begin{equation*} \lim_{x\to a} f(x),\quad \lim_{t\to a} f(t), \quad \lim_{y\to a} f(y),\end{equation*} all denote precisely the same number, which depends on
>   $f$ and $a$, and has nothing to do with $x,t$, or $y$ (these letters,
>   in fact, do not denote anything at all).  A more logical symbol would
>   be something like $\lim_a f$, but this notation, despite its brevity,
>   is so infuriatingly rigid that almost no one has seriously tried to
>   use it.  The notation $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ is much more useful
>   because a function $f$ often has no simple name, even though it might
>   be possible to express $f(x)$ by a simple formula involving $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Either way of speaking is common. You can speak about

- The limit of the *function* $f$ as *its argument* tends to $42$.

or

- The limit of the *expression* $3x^2+5x+\frac{\log x}{x}$ as $x$ tends to $42$.

In the second case, you can in particular consider the expression $f(x)$.

Neither of these is really more correct or precise than the other one. In mathematics you're generally supposed to pass back and forth effortlessly between a "function" and an "expression with a free variable in it", and use the perspective that makes most sense in any given context.

In the case of limits, there's the peculiarity that the *formal definition* of limits is usually phrased in terms of *functions* (because an expression is usually not considered a "thing" in itself that it looks nice to quantify a definition over, and a function is exactly *how* we pack up an expression as a thing when we need to), whereas the usual *notation* for concrete limits always works on *expressions* -- if you write $\lim_{x\to 42} 3x^2+5x+\frac{\log x}{x}$ there's no named function in sight, but the limit is perfectly good nevertheless.

However, don't say "the limit of $f$ for $x\to 42$. If you want to name the independent variable, you need to speak about the limit of an expression rather than a function.

Comment: You could also speak about "The limit of the function $\hspace{.04 in}f$ _at_ 42.", which is shorter. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Yes -- by mentioning the argument explicitly I was trying to emphasize that it _isn't_ the limit of $f$ as $x\to 42$.

Answer (score 2):

By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_on_the_real_line) one writes $\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(f(x)\right)=L$, if, and only if, there exists $L\in \Bbb R$ such that  $$\forall \varepsilon>0\exists \delta >0\forall x\in D_f \left(|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon\right).$$

This ($\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(f(x)\right)=L$) is simply a notation to convey the what is above, it's an abbreviation. In fact it isn't even a proper equality, it's just a string of symbols that happens to have the symbol $=$ in the middle. One only earns the right to define $\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(f(x)\right)$ as being equal to something after proving that an $L$ on the conditions above, must be unique.

If you want to mention the limit orally, I think it makes more sense to say 'limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $a$' (with the implied assumption that $f$ is a function on the variable $x$) than 'limit of $f$ of $x$ as $x$ approaches $a$', because, as I said, $\lim \limits_{x\to a}\left(f(x)\right)=L$ is just a notation and it's meaningless by itself, it's just short for what I said above.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it doesn't much matter -- even in the case that $f$ is a function of multiple variables, etc. it is hard to get too confused.

The statement that $f(x)$ denotes a value in the range of $f$, and not a function, is far from a universal convention. For instance

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$$
is particularly confusing: is it the derivative of $f$ with respect to the first factor, evaluated at $(x,y)$? The derivative of the function $[f(x,y)](x)$ with respect to $x$? What if you saw instead $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x^2,y)$$
or
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(\cdot, x)?$$